# How to insert 100,000 records in a single query in mySQL

Tags: mysql

How to insert 100000+ records in a table in mySQL database.

**What I think like :**

```
BEGIN
 declare i=0,n=100000;
 while (i<n) DO
  i++;
  insert into tableName values (1,2,3);
 END while;
END
```

**Why I need** : To test load on server if this much records are in database.

Is there any simple one line query which can work this?

Comment: This is likely better done with a scripting language. That would also allow you to generate random demo data. That being said 1000 records is nothing to any modern RDMS worth it's salt.

Comment: See this old chestnut... http://datacharmer.blogspot.co.uk/2006/06/filling-test-tables-quickly.html

Comment: @Strawberry, thats correct `;-)`

Comment: @halfer Well, you know, standards must be maintained!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Insert from the table back into itself:

```
insert into tableName values (1,2,3);
insert into tableName select * from tableName; -- 2 rows
insert into tableName select t.* from tableName t, tableName t2, tableName t3, tableName t4; -- raised to 4th power every execution
insert into tableName select t.* from tableName t, tableName t2, tableName t3, tableName t4; -- raised to 4th power every execution
```

Now there are 104994 rows

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7548/1)

You can add as many copies of the table to the cross join in one command as you like to increase the power to which the quantity is raised.

Comment: is it any way for changing vaules? eg. +100

Comment: @unbreak specifically what do you mean "+100"?

Comment: @Bohemian, i have in DB one column with values 1,2,3,4....100, now i will do insert into tableName select * from tableName; but i want them to start with 101,102... not again 1,2.. Something like this:
insert into tableName select code+100 from tableName;

Comment: @Bohemian `insert into test (code) SELECT code + 100 FROM test` Works!

Comment: @unbreak this works more generally: `insert into test select code + (select count(*) from test) from test`. No matter how many rows you had, every execution would double the number of rows and correctly number `code`.

Comment: @zik what needs explaining, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Using a [CTE](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/), on my machine inserting 100,000 records takes 0.7 seconds. Personally I feel this is easier to customize, e.g. remove the comment on the last line to make it a million records. Add or remove references to the CTE for more or less records, in powers of 10.

```
WITH 
  cteTen AS (
     SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
     SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL 
     SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
)
INSERT INTO 
  tableName SELECT 1, 2, 3  -- YOUR TABLE AND VALUES HERE
FROM cteTen AS X1, cteTen AS X2, cteTen AS X3, 
     cteTen AS X4, cteTen AS X5 --, cteTen AS X6
```

Comment: Hmmm - I didn't read the OP's tags - it's for MySQL. Not sure if MySQL supports CTEs yet???